# Build or form bonds with?

Tags: word-choice

Which sounds better? 
Is there a difference in formality or any other aspect?
Furthermore, are you aware of any better word choice?

*Example Sentence:* Thus, one have the opportunity to interact and ____ bonds with a not only talented but diverse group of individuals.

Thank you :)

Comment: I would say form bonds. This is a common expression, and I have not heard people say "build bonds with" very often, if at all.

Comment: Note it should be "one has", not "one have". I agree with DJ in regard to your actual question.

Comment: This is also possible: *to interact and bond with*.

Answer (score 2):

The formed sentence is clumsy. *'have'*, *'a'* are placed incorrectly. Also, the structure can be bettered.

As far as 'bond' is concerned **in this context**, you can...

> *form* a bond 
>  *strengthen* a bond **or simply..**
>  *have* a bond

Rephrased sentence could be:

> Thus, one *has an* opportunity to interact, and form/strengthen bonds *not only with* talented, but also *a* diverse group of individuals.

Comment: Thank you for your response Maulik. However, why isn't "the opportunity" correct and you replaced it with "an opportunity"?

Comment: That's because I am talking about 'opportunity' in general. If I'm specific about one particular opportunity, I'd use 'the'. Say--you are **invited** by ELL to share your experience with the site. This experience will be shared on the homepage of the ELL site. Now, I can say --Fokos, you should not miss **the** opportunity, go grab it!